# Error MSB3073 in visual studio 2017 when trying to build a project made with CMake

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

So I have the source files of a project and I made a visual studio 2017 project with CMake, when I try to build it I get this error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MSB3073 The command "setlocal
cd "C:\Users\Cristi\Desktop\siemens\curs\framework full\bin\src\spring\Application"
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
C:
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
"D:\pograml files\Cmake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_autogen "C:/Users/Cristi/Desktop/siemens/curs/framework full/bin/src/spring/Application/CMakeFiles/Application_autogen.dir/AutogenInfo.cmake" Debug
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
:cmEnd
endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
:cmErrorLevel
exit /b %1
:cmDone
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
:VCEnd" exited with code 1. Application D:\pograml files\visual studio2\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets    123
```

and this is the output related to the error, please ignore this and i have to write some more words because my post contains too much code, nice website btw

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Application, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>
1>AutoUic subprocess error
1>------------------------
1>The uic process failed to compile
1>  "C:/Users/Cristi/Desktop/siemens/curs/framework full/design/initial_scene.ui"
1>into
1>  "C:/Users/Cristi/Desktop/siemens/curs/framework full/bin/src/spring/Application/Application_autogen/include_Debug/ui_initial_scene.h"
1>included by
1>  "C:/Users/Cristi/Desktop/siemens/curs/framework full/src/spring/Application/InitialScene.cpp".
1>
1>Command
1>-------
1>D:/qt/5.10.1/msvc2017_64/bin/uic.exe -o "C:/Users/Cristi/Desktop/siemens/curs/framework full/bin/src/spring/Application/Application_autogen/include_Debug/ui_initial_scene.h" "C:/Users/Cristi/Desktop/siemens/curs/framework full/design/initial_scene.ui"
1>
1>Output
1>------
1>uic: Error in line 2, column 36 : Unexpected attribute idbasedtr
1>File 'C:/Users/Cristi/Desktop/siemens/curs/framework full/design/initial_scene.ui' is not valid
1>
1>D:\pograml files\visual studio2\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(123,5): error MSB3073: The command "setlocal
1>D:\pograml files\visual studio2\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(123,5): error MSB3073: cd "C:\Users\Cristi\Desktop\siemens\curs\framework full\bin\src\spring\Application"
1>D:\pograml files\visual studio2\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(123,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
1>D:\pograml files\visual studio2\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(123,5): error MSB3073: C:
1>D:\pograml files\visual studio2\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(123,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
1>D:\pograml files\visual studio2\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(123,5): error MSB3073: "D:\Cmake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_autogen "C:/Users/Cristi/Desktop/siemens/curs/framework full/bin/src/spring/Application/CMakeFiles/Application_autogen.dir/AutogenInfo.cmake" Debug
1>D:\pograml files\visual studio2\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(123,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
1>D:\pograml files\visual studio2\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(123,5): error MSB3073: :cmEnd
1>D:\pograml files\visual studio2\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(123,5): error MSB3073: endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
1>D:\pograml files\visual studio2\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(123,5): error MSB3073: :cmErrorLevel
1>D:\pograml files\visual studio2\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(123,5): error MSB3073: exit /b %1
1>D:\pograml files\visual studio2\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(123,5): error MSB3073: :cmDone
1>D:\pograml files\visual studio2\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(123,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
1>D:\pograml files\visual studio2\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(123,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 1.
1>Done building project "Application.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
2>------ Build started: Project: Loader, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
2>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\..\Debug\Application.lib'
2>Done building project "Loader.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
3>------ Skipped Build: Project: ALL_BUILD, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
3>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
4>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: ZERO_CHECK, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
4>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
5>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: Framework, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
5>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
6>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: Application, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
6>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
7>------ Skipped Deploy: Project: Loader, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
7>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 2 failed, 2 up-to-date, 1 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 4 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Can you post the full output? Usually with errors like this there is a more verbose error message further up in the output.

Comment: thanks for trying to help, i will edit my post the output is too long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're compiling a Qt based project maybe?

Based on the output it looks like the `uic` executable that translates qt `*.ui` files to `*.h` files is failing on a particular file:

```
The uic process failed to compile
1>  "C:/Users/Cristi/Desktop/siemens/curs/framework full/design/initial_scene.ui"
```

I would double check that this file exists and open it in Qt Creator to see if that would fix it.